# how to see oneself edges using java3d transparency

Tags: java, transparency, java-3d

When setting an object's transparency on in Java3D, I cant see the other objects through that object but I can't see this very object geometry through it. Is that possible ?

(example: I have a transparent cube that is lit a way that the faces have different colors, however, I can only see at most 3 faces of the cube at the same time)

Answer (score 0):

This probably has something to do with Culling.
Check out this example: http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/java3d/j3d_tutorial_ch2.pdf
Go to page 2-42, section 2.6.4. I have a feeling it has to do with that.